# Cardgame that uses a loop to check which card in a card game is the highest in value

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a card game that essentially returns(in a string) the card that was the highest card played. There are four players and the player who had the highest card wins. Although essentially all that's going to happen is that the highest card in the string will win, and such a value is returned as a string. So if the string was "Kc3h2sJd" the method should return as "Kc" since king of clovers was the highest card played.
Basically, my question is how can I simply develop a hierarchy for these cards and compare them at their indexes? Here is my method so far:

```
public String winningCard(String play) {
    char highestcard = play.charAt(0);

    char T = 10;
    char J = 11;
    char Q = 12;
    char K = 13;
    char A = 14;


    for (int i = 0; i < play.length(); i = i + 2) {
        if (highestcard < play.charAt(i)) {
            highestcard = play.charAt(i);            
        } else if (highestcard > play.charAt(i)) {
            highestcard = play.charAt(0);

    }

}
    String winner = String.valueOf(highestcard);
    return winner;
}
```

Am I on the right track here? (T represents 10, jack 11, and so on.) Or is there a far more efficient method of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I am curious in what part of the world do they call ♣ "clovers"? The name I heard in the US is "clubs".

Comment: Could your code get compiled successfully ?

Comment: you should run it and see

Comment: Frankly, no, I don’t think that is going to work for you, sorry.

Comment: Java is playing a trick on you here. You are declaring a char variable T, so this variable is supposed to hold a character. 10 is an int, and java is letting you assign it anyway, pretending all is well. It isn’t.

Comment: I wish I could tell you something more constructive, but it would have to depend on your prerequisites. Personally I’d probably write a `Card` class to represent the card values and have the method accept four `Card` instances rather than a string of length 8. I might also use a `HashMap` to translate from char (0 through 9, T, J, Q, K, A) to value as an integer. If the ideas are not too advanced for you, they’re yours.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, some (many?) European languages have a name for clubs that would translate to clovers. For instance French “trèfles“ or Danish “klør” (short for “kløver”).

Comment: @OleV.V. Unfortunately yes, that does sound outside my level. Would showing all the prerequisites help? They're quite lengthy so I thought I'd avoid doing so because some people may interpret the intention of this question as doing my homework(i'm just learning java on my own time).

Comment: I will try to keep my suggestions basic. You’re thinking in card values as numbers from 2 through 14, this is right because you need numbers to compare to find out which is the highest. So in addition to `char highestcard` also declare `int highestValue` and always update both. Make an auxiliary method `static int value(char card)` so that `value('2')` returns 2, `value('T')` returns 10 etc. In your for loop, call this method, and if the value is higher than highestValue, assign to both highestcard and highestValue so they always agree. BTW I believe you don’t need the `else if` part.